# Compatible antivirus software with OneDrive Files On-Demand enabled

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, antivirus

We've recently deployed OneDrive for Business with Files On-Demand enabled to users (Windows 10 machines) and shortly after some PCs started to freeze up with 100% disk usage. We found that the antivirus software was causing some kind of conflict. ESET Endpoint Antivirus is the one installed on the affected PCs.

Microsoft has [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-onedrive-files-on-demand-0e6860d3-d9f3-4971-b321-7092438fb38e) which explains some basic stuff about OneDrive Files On-Demand, with this note:

> Files On-Demand might not be compatible with some third-party antivirus solutions.

However, I've not been able to find any kind of list regarding which antivirus suites are compatible with OneDrive Files On-Demand.

I'd like to avoid downloading and testing trial versions if at all possible.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OneDrive is seen as a folder on the local computer the workstations are most likely all scanning the network files at the same time which would certainly cause issues. I would recommend creating and exclusion policy on the workstations for that folder. One Drive for Business scans files when they are uploaded and isolates them if there is an infection found, and will not allow that file to be synced to a workstation. Sadly this makes you reliant on Microsoft's scan ability to detect infections. Your mileage may very with other anti virus but I personally would not be too keen to replace ESET as it is great in my opinion.

this article may help
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Virus-detection-in-SharePoint-Online-e3c6df61-8513-499d-ad8e-8a91770bff63

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. We've already excluded the OneDrive folders from the ESET scans which seemed to work, but weren't keen on having all the OneDrive files unprotected - but the article you posted answers that one.